# Writing proofs in mathematics: prove that $xy+5$ is an even integer if $x$ and $y$ are odd integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

here is what I have so far:

by definition an integer is called odd if there exists an integer $k$ such that $y=2k+1$ so if $y$ and $x$ are any two odd integers the product of those two integers added to $5$ is an even integer. $(xy + 5)$ is an even integer.

I need help figuring out how to prove it correctly

Comment: You need to link up your ideas - you put down a definition of an odd number but you never use it either to calculate anything or to show that any number conforms to that definition, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all you've done is quote the "definition" of an odd number and just restate the conclusion, not taken steps to prove anything.

Here's a hint to get you started: let $x = 2m+1$ and $y =2n+1$. $m$ and $n$ are not necessarily equal, of course, but both $x$ and $y$ are clearly odd. Now try multiplying those expressions, add $5$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Good start! Let $x = 2x_1+1$ and $y = 2y_1 + 1$. Then we need to prove $(2x_1+1)(2y_1+1)+5$ is even.

Expanding, we get $$(2x_1+1)(2y_1+1)+5$$$$4x_1y_1+2x_1+2y_1+1+5$$$$4x_1y_1+2x_1+2y_1+6$$

For a number to be even it must be divisible by $2$. Luckily we can factor a two from this expression! We have $$2(2x_1y_1+x_1+y_1+3).$$

Since $x_1$ and $y_1$ are integers, the above expression must be even, and we are done.

---

General useful tips for proofs:

- **Focus on what stands out.** Here, it was the odd integer values. Expressing these odd integer values differently was the key here.
- **Understand what to prove.** Fortunately, this proof was pretty straightforward. However, later in your math career you will probably run into proofs with harder notation and concepts that may throw you off. Always make sure you understand what to prove before you actually try to prove it.
- **Experiment.** If proving something in geometry, try drawing different diagrams. If proving number theory like this problem, express numbers in different ways. Experiment to get creative!